How to Reapply Custom Extender Logic to PrimeFaces p:schedule After update() Call?
I'm using the PrimeFaces p:schedule component in my JSF application with a custom JavaScript extender that adds additional content to each event using the eventContent property in FullCalendar. However, I’m facing a two-part issue with keeping this extender logic applied after updates.
Problem Breakdown:

Regenerating JavaScript from Backing Bean: I generate the extender JavaScript dynamically from my backing bean, as shown below:


<h:panelGroup id="scriptPanel">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        #{appointmentsController.generateJsCustomization()}
    </script>
</h:panelGroup>

public String generateJsCustomization() {
    ScheduleConfig config = new ScheduleConfig(
        "", // dayCellContent
        "", // slotLaneContentDay
        "", // slotLaneContentWeek
        scheduleConfig.getBusinessHours() // businessHours
    );
    
    this.jsExtenderCode = JavaScriptGenerator.generateCustomizeSchedule(config, 
        appointments.stream()
            .flatMap(appointment -> appointment.getPatientAppointments().stream())
            .collect(Collectors.toList())
    );
    return this.jsExtenderCode;
}

The JavaScript extender function (jsExtenderCode) is generated correctly, but when I update the schedule, the generated JavaScript isn’t re-rendered on the page. It seems the scriptPanel doesn’t re-render with each update.

Reapplying Extender Logic After Schedule Update: When I call PF('myScheduleWidgetVar').update() to refresh the schedule, it fetches event data efficiently without a full re-render, meaning that my custom extender logic for modifying eventContent does not reapply automatically after each update.

Documentation Insight
According to the PrimeFaces documentation:

“Schedule provides a simple client-side API and the update method. Whenever you call update, schedule will query its server-side ScheduleModel instance to check for updates... this approach is much more effective than updating with regular PPR.”

Given that update() doesn’t trigger a full re-render, my extender logic needs to be reapplied after every update.
Question
How can I:

Ensure that the generated JavaScript in generateJsCustomization() is re-rendered on the page after each update?
Reapply the extender logic to the p:schedule component to add custom eventContent after calling update()?

Any suggestions on how to handle both parts of this issue effectively would be greatly appreciated!

Have you already found and tried https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/autoUpdate.xhtml?

@BalusC Thanks for suggesting <p:autoUpdate>! It worked to re-render the JavaScript on AJAX updates. The remaining issue was with my extender logic

The remaining issue was with the logic in the JavaScript function, not with reapplying the extender itself. Appreciate the tip!

Another option even though @BalusC suggestions are great you can just override the Schedule update widget method to call your extender after its called.
if (PrimeFaces.widget.Schedule) {
  PrimeFaces.widget.Schedule.update = function() {
    this.calendar.refetchEvents();

    if (this.cfg.extender) {
      this.cfg.extender.call(this);
    }
  }
}

Although it sounds like you need the extender script updated first so @BalusC solution of using <p:autoUpdate /> sounds like the right solution for you.
